# Make email form disappear after email is sent - jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, email

I'm currently trying to create an email form with Wordpress. I've gotten the form to function correctly, however I want to make it FadeOut when the email is successfully sent, but not when the email doesn't (e.g., when a field is left blank, etc). You can see for yourself here. Also below are the codes:

http://www.matthewruddy.com/demo/?page_id=719

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$('.contactform-main input#submit').click(function() {
    $('.preload-icon').html('<img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/images/preload.gif" class="loaderIcon" alt="Loading." />');

    var name = $('input#name').val();
    var email = $('input#email').val();
    var comments = $('textarea.comments-text').val();
    var mailto = $('input#mailto').val();
    var admin = $('input#admin').val()

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/functions/submit-email.php',
        data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&comments=' + comments + '&mailto=' + mailto +'&admin=' + admin,

        success: function(results) {
            $('.contactform-main img.loaderIcon').fadeOut(600);
            $('div.response').html(<?php _e(results, 'lr_framework'); ?>);
        }
    }); // end ajax
});
});
</script>
```

And the PHP :

```
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$site_owners_email = $_POST['mailto']; // Replace this with your own email address
$site_owners_name = $_POST['admin']; // replace with your name

if (strlen($name) < 2) {
    $error['name'] = 'Please enter your name';
}

if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
    $error['email'] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
}

if (strlen($comments) < 3) {
    $error['comments'] = 'Please leave a comment.';
}

if (!$error) {

    require_once('phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->Subject = "Website Contact Form";
    $mail->AddAddress($site_owners_email, $site_owners_name);
    $mail->Body = $comments;

    $mail->Send();

    ?><div class="success"><ul><li><?php printf('Congratulations %s, your message was successfully sent. Thank you!', $name); ?></li></ul></div><?php

} # end if no error
else {
    $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? "<li>" . $error['name'] . "</li> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? "<li>" . $error['email'] . "</li> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['comments'])) ? "<li>" . $error['comments'] . "</li>" : null;

    echo '<div class="error"><ul>'. $response .'</ul></div>';
} # end if there was an error sending

?>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/functions/submit-email.php',
        data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&comments=' + comments + '&mailto=' + mailto +'&admin=' + admin,

        success: function(results) {
            $('.contactform-main img.loaderIcon').fadeOut(600);
            $('.contactform-main').fadeOut(600); // This will hide the form
            $('div.response').html(<?php _e(results, 'lr_framework'); ?>);
        }
    }); // end ajax
```

To clarify, `success` method checks for successful AJAX execution not for PHP code execution. So if you want to handle a PHP error in your jQuery code you need some index showing that e.g. True/False. To accomplish that you can use [**JSON**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

PHP Example:

```
$response = array();
$result = $mail->send();
$response['result'] = $result;

if($result) {
    $response['message'] = 'The email was sent successfully!';
} else {
    $response['message'] = 'There was an error. Please try again!';
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

[**jQuery AJAX Example**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
      url: "email.php",
      global: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: ({text : "Your text here"}),
      dataType: "json",
      async:false,
      success: function(data){
         if(data["result"]) {
             alert(data["message"]); // Success
         } else {
             alert(data["message"]); // Fail
         }
      }
   }
)
```

But you should take the error/success box out of the form DIV tag or it will fade out too.

Comment: This doesn't check to see if the form was submitted successfully or not.

Comment: Yes, this will fade the form out even if the message doesn't send.

Comment: you should use JSON and return array, eg: array('successful'=>1, 'message'=>'Enter HTML here'); in the javascript just check successful parameter. For PHP use json_encode() to transform your array.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would suggest - return some kind of tuple with an error/success flag and the message. In your AJAX callback, you can check to see if it was an error/success and handle it appropriately.

Comment: The way the code works though is that even if the message doesn't send it acts as though it has been a success except the PHP executed tells the variable to display the error message. If the message does send then this variable is just changed to the success message. Either way, the AJAX treats the request as a success.. I'm not really sure how to change this.. Only a novice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending back some response back to the AJAX function via your PHP, and handle if it was a success or error in the Javascript callback.

Comment: How can this be done? I've tried using die() but that didn't seem to work.